# buttongroup item is pressed and cant click more time

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

In Delphi i have a `buttongroup` in my form that I created 10 button items programmatically on it.

When I click on 3rd button it do the `showmessage` or any other function pointed.

Like this sample code

```
procedure TForm2.ButtonGroup1ButtonClicked(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer);
begin
  showmessage( Index.ToString );
end;
```

But when I click on 3rd button again it do nothing, and it is look like pressed yet...

i tried to set `intemindex` or `refresh` or `repaint` or `realign`.but nothing worked!!

how can i fix this !? is this a buffered option?!

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Tokyo (just wanted to say).

Comment: I've experimented something similar once. If I remember correctly I solved with a `ReleaseCapture` call before anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change this by set the `gboGroupStyle` property in `ButtonOptions` as 
False

tested in `rad studio,berlin`

[image]